# "The user does not exist or is not unique" when pasting the same name

Tags: custom-list

While in *edit mode*, I paste several rows worth of data into my list. One of the columns is a Person/Group field.

I keep getting an error message telling me that the "user does not exist or is not unique."

To solve it I select that cell and type in the name that was there in the first place, but this time the predicted name pops-up and I select it. This can really slow things down when I have a lot of records to upload.

So why is it that it doesn't recognize the name when I paste it, but it does when I retype it?

Answer (score 0):

Person and Group fields search for the user and resolve the user with presence by using the user's SharePoint ID.  Try replacing the names with their SharePoint user IDs and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to paste names of users in people or group, it will not get resolved as it is not considered a unique property.

You can try to paste the email address of users (I have used this earlier) or SharePoint User Id (generated in User Profiles)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I replaced names with `i:0#.f|membership|` + email address (for example: `i:0#.f|membership|abc@company.com`), and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The People or Group field is a lookup column that uses the people picker which needs to query the site collection User List in the content DB to find the matching loginName mapped to that user. Pasting the name in the field does not allow the people picker to conduct that query. You would need to type it in in order to give it the chance to conduct a search.

One way around that is to set a default person or group value for that field, like [Current User]. Another option you can try is to use the loginName (domain\jrsmith) when cutting/pasting.